# Calling a variable to reference an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a string variable to reference an array variable.

```
message1[0][0] = "Hello."; // existing array
var caller = ['message1', 'message2', 'message3'];

alert(message1[0][0]);
```

But instead of using the message1 array in the alert, I want to use caller[0] (which is equal to "message1") so that it displays "Hello". How do you do this? This doesn't seem to work:

```
alert(caller[0][0][0]);
```

Comment: `message1[caller[0]]`, but you really want an plain Object I think.

Comment: Note: You don't *call* variables. You use them, access them, refer to them, get them, set them... You call *functions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to put `message1` on an object, then use `[]` notation to index into the object:

```js
var obj = {
  message1: [
    ["Hello.", "two", "three"]
    ]
};
var caller = ['message1', 'message2', 'message3'];

alert(obj[caller[0]][0][0]);
```

If `message1` is a global variable, it's already on an object — the global object, which you can access as `window` on browsers. So if it's a global, you could use:

```
alert(window[caller[0]][0][0]);
```

But global variables are a Bad Idea<sup>(tm)</sup>, so best to use your own object instead.

---

Full disclosure: You can also use `eval` to do it, but it's a big hammer for a task this small. Just for completeness:

```
alert(eval(caller[0] + "[0][0]"));
```

I don't recommend it, but provided you're fully in control of the text you pass into it, it's workable. Much better to use an object, though.

Comment: The first one is the best way what I think.

Comment: And that's why it's first. :-)

Comment: This is a very good answer, and it already worked as a global variable, but I want to use the object one, and it doesn't seem to work yet. So: message1 starts out as a blank array. My question is, do you declare the array inside the object like this: message1: []?

Comment: @ken_vitreous: Yup. It's much the same as an assignment statement, but with a `:` instead of a `=`. The bit after the `:` can be any expression, including an empty array. (That thing is called a "property initialiser"; the `{...}` thing is an "object initialiser" [sometimes called an "object literal"].) Best,

Comment: The explanations are very insightful. Thanks a lot!